# analyzing STATSPACK report

Tags: performance, oracle9i, statspack

I am looking for a free tool that can analyzes  ORACLE 9i statspack report and recommend ways to optimize the DB.
Is there such a tool or something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of sites out there.  [OraPerf.com](http://www.oraperf.com/) and [StatspackAnalyzer.com](http://www.txmemsys.com/statspack-reg.htm).

Be aware, however, that automated systems like this are generally quite a bit more limited in what they can recommend than a competent human reviewing the material.  They are also biased in that they tend to recommend things that will benefit the sponsoring company.  Without seeing your Statspack report, I would wager that StatspackAnalyzer.com will make multiple recommendations to move to solid-state disk.  It's worth noting that one of the companies that sponsors the site also happens to sell solid-state disks.